# Uniform convergence on the interval $[0,a].$

Tags: sequences-and-series

Let 
$$f_n(x) = 4^{n}(x^{2^{n}}-x^{2^{n+1}}).$$
Then I wan to show that $f_n(x)$ is uniformly convergent in on the interval $[0,a]$ where $a\in [0,1).$

I looked at the solution and the author says that for large enough $n$ we have that 
$$\sup_{0\leq x\leq a}|f_n(x)| = f_{n}(a).$$
I do not understand why this is true. Perhaps someone could explain?

I know that that $f_{n}(x)$ takes its maximum value at $x = \frac{1}{2^{1/2^n}}\to 1 $ (as $n\to \infty$) on the interval $[0,1].$ And so I guess if $n$ is large enough then $\frac{1}{2^{1/2^n}}$ will miss the interval $[0,a]$ and so all values of $x\in[0,a]$ the function will be increasing and thus their supremum equals the $f_n(a).$ Is this the reasoning behind this claim?

Comment: Yes. Just observe the derivative of $f_n'$ on $[0,a]$, from which I think you would have got the maximum value. Check that if $n$ is small enough then the derivative will be positive on that interval. Write down the derivative first, though, for context.

Answer (score 1):

It is not necessary to find $\max_{x\in [0,a]}|f_n(x)|.$

If $0\le a <1$ then $\lim_{n\to \infty}a^n=0$ so there exists $k_a\in \Bbb N $ such that $a^{k_a}\le 1/8.$

And $\lim_{n\to \infty}n/2^n= 0$ so there exists $n_a\in \Bbb N$ such that $\forall n\ge n_a\,(2^n\ge k_an).$

So for $n\ge n_a$ and $x\in [0,a]$ we have $$0\le f_n(x)=4^n(x^{2^n})(1-x^{2^n}) \le$$ $$\le 4^n(x^{2^n})\le$$ $$\le 4^n(a^{2^n})\le$$ $$\le 4^n(a^{k_an})=$$ $$=4^n (a^{k_a})^n\le$$ $$\le  4^n (1/8)^n=2^{-n}.$$ Therefore $\forall n\ge n_a \;(\; \sup_{x\in [0,a]}|f_n(x)|\le 2^{-n}\;).$

Answer (score 0):

A more precise statement is : $\sup_{0\leq x \leq a} |f_n(x)|=f_n(a)$ if $a^{2^{n}} <\frac 1 2$. For this write $f_n(x)$ as $4^{n}x^{2^{n}}(1-x^{2^{n}})$. The function $t \to t(1-t)$ is increasing in $[0,\frac 1 2]$. Hence $f_n$ is increasing on $[0,a]$ provided $a^{2^{n}} <\frac 1 2$. This inequality holds for $n$ sufficiently large.